# Matchmaker server in Unity3D: suddenly crash.

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-unet

Matchmaker server in Unity3D is always crashing after 2-6 minutes when first client is connected with this errors: [screenshot of errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6vLgC.png).

Where can be the error? Am I missed any special network settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem was in unity matchmaker servers bandwidth. Details [here](https://forum.unity3d.com/threads/matchmaker-client-timeout.342745/).